# How to add my html code into Blogger post without affecting Blogger's theme style tags?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm new to html and css. I created a small code to use in my blog post (in Blogger). The issue is when I add the code into my post, the style sheet linked to my code interacts with the blog's theme and the theme and my code behaves improperly.

For example, the style of contents in "container" tag of the blog (which may be present in menu, side bars, footers etc.) changes according to the style sheet, that the code is linked to. Similarly all the input fields present on that post changes their style according to css of the code, that I added. Even the border of the post takes the style of border of the input fields of the code!

Is there any way to keep the style sheet separate so that it only works for container and input tags of the contents of the code and doesn't affect the container and input tags of all other content preset on that page?

```css
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    input[type=text], select, textarea {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        resize: vertical;
     font-family: Sans-serif;
     font-size: 19px;
    }



    .container {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 20px;
     

        float: center;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 3px solid black;
     

    }
     

</style>
```

```html
<code>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://myhosting.com/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="container">
      <form>
      
      
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-25"><label for="fname">Enter First name</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter ..."></div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-25"><label for="fname">Enter Last name</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><input type="text" id="lname" name="lasttname" placeholder="Enter.."></div>
       </div>
      
     
      </form>
      

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>

</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do that you need to add custom selectors (classes or id's) to your HTML and use them in your stylesheet to add new styles like in the example below.

Here you add `class="custom-class-name"` to your input in html:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25"><label for="fname">Enter Last name</label></div>
      <div class="col-75"><input class="custom-class-name" type="text" id="lname" name="lasttname" placeholder="Enter.."></div>
  </div>
```

and then you use this class to add new styles for it:

```
   input.custom-class-name {
     width: 50%;
     border: 2px solid red;
   }
```

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    input[type=text], select, textarea {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        resize: vertical;
     font-family: Sans-serif;
     font-size: 19px;
    }

    .container {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        float: center;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 3px solid black;
    }
   
   input.custom-class-name {
   width: 50%;
   border: 2px solid red;
   }
```

```html
<code>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://myhosting.com/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="container">
      <form>
      
      
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-25"><label for="fname">Enter First name</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter ..."></div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-25"><label for="fname">Enter Last name</label></div>
              <div class="col-75"><input class="custom-class-name" type="text" id="lname" name="lasttname" placeholder="Enter.."></div>
       </div>
      
     
      </form>
      

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>

</code>
```

Another way to do that is adding inline styles to you html (which is actually not good approach but it works):

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25"><label for="fname">Enter Last name</label></div>
      <div class="col-75"><input style="width: 50%; border: 2px solid red;" type="text" id="lname" name="lasttname" placeholder="Enter.."></div>
  </div>
```

But this are the basic of [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) which you should read (click the provided links).